# find multiple count with multiple join sql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join, inner-join

I am having four tables with structure like

```
Destinations:
id , destination_name 

Activities:
id , destination_id

Attractions:
id , destination_id 

Fair :
id , destination_id
```

and i am using

```
SELECT  d.id AS id, 
        d.destination_name AS destination_name,
        d.destination_type AS destination_type, 
        d.is_active AS is_active, 
        d.meta_description AS meta_description, 
        d.meta_keywords AS meta_keywords, 
        d.meta_title AS meta_title, 
        COUNT(att.id) AS attractions, 
        COUNT(act.id) AS activitys, 
        COUNT(f.destination_id) AS fairs 
FROM    destinations AS d 
        LEFT JOIN attractions AS att 
            ON d.id= att.destination_id 
        LEFT JOIN category_destination_ref AS act 
            ON d.id = act.destination_id 
        LEFT JOIN fairnfestival AS f 
            ON d.id = f.destination_id 
GROUP BY d.id 
ORDER BY d.id DESC
```

but it is giving me sum in "attractions" and "fairs" coloumns

Comment: can you explain a little about your problem

Comment: when i am getting results it gives me worng count in two fields i.e.  attraction and fairs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are joining more than one 1-n relationship, so in the simplest terms if you have 2 attractions and two fairs for each one destination a simple join will give you a cartesian product of the fairs and attractions:

```
DestinationID   FairID  AttractionID
1               1       1
1               1       2
1               2       1
1               2       2
```

As you can see, there are only 2 values for `FairID`, but 4 rows so a count will produce 4, and not 2 that you expect.

You either need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT att.id) AS attractions`, e.g:

```
SELECT  d.id AS id, 
        d.destination_name AS destination_name,
        d.destination_type AS destination_type, 
        d.is_active AS is_active, 
        d.meta_description AS meta_description, 
        d.meta_keywords AS meta_keywords, 
        d.meta_title AS meta_title, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT att.id) AS attractions, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT act.id) AS activitys, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT f.id) AS fairs 
FROM    destinations AS d 
        LEFT JOIN attractions AS att 
            ON d.id= att.destination_id 
        LEFT JOIN category_destination_ref AS act 
            ON d.id = act.destination_id 
        LEFT JOIN fairnfestival AS f 
            ON d.id = f.destination_id 
GROUP BY d.id 
ORDER BY d.id DESC;
```

Or move your aggregations to subqueries:

```
SELECT  d.id AS id, 
        d.destination_name AS destination_name,
        d.destination_type AS destination_type, 
        d.is_active AS is_active, 
        d.meta_description AS meta_description, 
        d.meta_keywords AS meta_keywords, 
        d.meta_title AS meta_title, 
        COALESCE(att.attractions, 0) AS attractions, 
        COALESCE(act.activitys, 0) AS activities, 
        COALESCE(f.fairs, 0) AS fairs
FROM    destinations AS d 
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  att.Destination_ID, COUNT(att.id) AS Attractions
            FROM    attractions AS att
            GROUP BY att.Destination_ID
        ) AS att 
            ON d.id = att.destination_id 
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  act.Destination_ID, COUNT(act.id) AS activities
            FROM    category_destination_ref AS act
            GROUP BY act.Destination_ID
        ) AS act
            ON d.id = act.destination_id 
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  f.Destination_ID, COUNT(f.id) AS fairs
            FROM    fairnfestival AS f
            GROUP BY f.Destination_ID
        ) AS f
            ON d.id = f.destination_id
ORDER BY d.id DESC;
```

I suspect the former will perform better in MySQL as it doesn't deal with subqueries that well, but the latter is required if you need to start doing SUMs as `SUM(DISTINCT` won't work.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT f.destination_id)` is always returns 1 because of `JOIN ON d.id = f.destination_id`. I think here should be something `COUNT(DISTINCT f.id)` where f.id is a primary key for f (if exists???).